# If you extend an XTemplate in Sencha Touch, how can you specify the template text value?

Tags: sencha-touch-2

Instead of having a control where we concatenate a huge HTML string, I'd like to separate the XTemplate object into its own file.  The problem is that I don't know how to set the template text in this class.  Normally, you'd create a new XTemplate object in-line and pass the template text as the first parameter.

Is this possible?  What property should I be setting?

```
/**
 * Custom XTemplate
 */
Ext.define('MyApp.view.MySuperDuperXTemplate', {
    extend: 'Ext.XTemplate',
    xtype: 'mySuperDuperXTemplate',

    html: 'Does the template text go here?',
    text: 'That didn\'t work, let me try this...',
    tpl: 'How about this?  No?...'
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

XTemplate gets the HTML when you pass it in the constructor, so you would need to override that to create it:

```
Ext.define('Test', {
    extend: 'Ext.XTemplate',

    html: 'testing',

    constructor: function() {
        return this.callParent([this.html]);
    }
});

// Then use it
new Test();
```

Comment: Thanks!  Quick question: It doesn't seem to matter what you call the property, correct?  You can call it html, text, or mySuperDuperProperty.  It seems to just be a temporary property used to pass to the constructor, correct?